# Using Archer abilities with Swords

Tags: final-fantasy-rpg

I'm trying out this old RPG called [FFRPG](http://www.returnergames.com/complete.html), and we haven't even begun playing when one of my player's character sheet stood out :(

One of my players created an Archer with a Special Training Advantage: Ninja Swords with the Two-Hands skill as high as it can get (named [Shiro Emiya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archer_%28Fate/stay_night%29)). Of course, he has two ninja swords, and told me that the Archer abilities didn't have any restrictions on which weapons it can apply to :( However, most Final Fantasy games has strict weapons proficiency rules: Squall can only use Gunblades, Cloud can only use Greatswords and Zidane can use either Swallows or Knives.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any weapons restrictions on abilities at the FFRPG rulebook. Should I allow it or not?

Comment: Are you looking for rules reasons for allowing/disallowing? Or opinions on if this seemingly unintentional combination is overpowered and therefor should get disallowed? Or something else? Or all of the above?

Comment: There's a Final Fantasy RPG? ...*follows first link*... It's kind of polished for a pure fan effort.

Comment: since when dose a DM have to search the rules to find a good reason to ban the broken?  If you think it will brake the game have him change it, add in proficiency restrictions if you like. You are the Game Master, Make the call you are most comfortable with.

Comment: @Rent_ZHB It's a common enough approach – a lot of people default to it when learning to run games on their own, just trying to "do it right". And there are enough games now that are written as "complete" (indie and trad) systems that don't *need* creative interpretation – and expect the GM not to – that it's a common approach even among experienced GMs now.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie that is the problem with rpg design (even the ones that start off with an intro page that says that Role playing/ running the game is less rules and more rulings) they all seem to elevate the rules in the books higher then they should be.  It jest boggles me to think that the rules need to be written by some one else in a published format for some people to accept it.  In short it is the books that ask players to look through the books to verify that the GM "Keeps To the rules" that makes being a GM hard.

Comment: @Rent *shrug* It depends on the game. Especially games where the GM is designed to be just another player with different duties, it does work. There are games where it doesn't work. It's not an inherent problem, but depends on the context of the rules.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do you *want* to allow it?

Ask yourself that, and just do that.

Comment: "Hey, don't bend the rules like that. If you do, you're going to force me to be a jerk GM and say no. And abusing the rules enough to force me to do that is being a jerk player. So cut it out."

Comment: "Also if you do it, you guys might meet a lot of archers with bigger swords."

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like the player is taking this from FF Tactics. That's kind of a common build in that series, actually. Of course, bows need 2 hands to wield, so you can't use 2 at once, regardless of what weapons a given ability does or doesn't allow. (Unless it explicitly says it allows it, of course. But in this case, it just doesn't make any sense.)

Answer (score 3):

I bumped Lohoris's answer, because its always the right one... sort of. You, as GM, need to be the final arbiter of what is and is not allowable (because someone needs to be). However, it is generally good to discuss things with your players to understand why they made a decision and to work with them to mitigate any worries you might have before disallowing their choice out-right. After all, if we didn't want to be able to do things outside the rules we'd be playing video RPGs instead! But this is a little much for a comment. From the RAW:

> Weapons lists the Weapon types this Job is proficient with. Weapon
> types not listed in a Job’s profile may not be wielded by a character
> unless they have the Advantage Special Training. The one exception
> to this are Thrown Weapons, which may be used by all Jobs.
>
> Weapons: Boomerangs, Bows, Crossbows, Rifles

The rules are fairly clear on whether he can USE those weapons. (He took the special training advantage, after all.)

The abilities themselves, on the other hand, don't say anything explicit about weapon usage (other than snipe mentioning a ranged weapon). They do, however use 'fire' repeatedly, which implies a bow, crossbow, or rifle. (Based on the weapons list.)

Still without reading the *entire* rules, I don't see any particular reason why this combination (although thematically inappropriate to the name Archer) would be particularly problematic. It would simply represent a close combat fighter who excels in hitting critical locations. If you see a particular feature that seems like it would be easily abused (in a way it could not be if using a ranged weapon) then you might want to discuss limiting that ability.

Comment: Or he fires swords like arrows.

Comment: @Pureferret Certainly the sort of thing I'D put the kibosh on. Although it is FF. Gunsword becomes a Swordgun. :-)

Comment: Or [sword](http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2009/359/b/3/Concept_Art__Bow_Sword_by_MercyGiver.jpg)[bow](http://www.beyondxanadu.com/resources/images/Mark/Elven_Bowsword.jpg)